# How Can the Number of Degrees of Freedom per Frequency in the Rayleigh-Jean formula be Irrational, or are they not?

Tags: thermal-radiation, classical-field-theory

I've read that the Rayleigh-Jean formula for the energy density per frequency of blackbody radiation can be expressed as $u(ν,T) = nkT$ where k is Boltzmann's constant, T is the temperature, and n is defined as the number of Degrees of Freedom per frequency ν and is equal to $\frac{8πν^2}{c^3} $ .

I assume that the number of Degrees of Freedom of *anything* is discrete quantity, however, this equation seems to imply that the number of Degrees of Freedom could be irrational for reasons such as the appearance of π in numerator. Is it, in fact, the case that the number of degrees of freedom for a given frequency can be irrational? If so, what would that mean (rather, what does it mean to have a non-interger degree of freedom)? Or does the irrationality of n vanish after one multiplies out all of the terms such that the other terms 'compensate' for π's irrationality?

Comment: First of all, $\nu^2/c^3$ is not dimensionless, so it's not a number...

Comment: You're right about that. This was an expression I took directly from McMahon's "Quantum Mechanics Demystified", and I'm either hopelessly confused by this equation and its logic or it makes no sense.

Comment: That is an approximation of the number of degrees of freedom per unit frequency per unit volume.